# Asserting a method is called with a parameter that is contained within a set of values using Mockito

Tags: mockito

Is there a way with Mockito to verify that a method is called with a parameter that within a closed set. For example, can I assert that a method

```
void addToNotWorthyList(String guitaristName);
```

is called with guitaristName is within the set ("Jeff Beck", "Seasick Steve", "Steve Howe")?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
verify(systemUnderTest).addToNotWorthyList(argThat(isOneOf(
    "Jeff Beck", "SeasickSteve", "Steve Howe")));
```

This uses Hamcrest's [`isOneOf`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#isOneOf%28T...%29), which is available in 1.3 at least. If you already have the items in a collection or array, skip directly to [`isIn`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#isIn%28java.util.Collection%29).

```
verify(systemUnderTest).addToNotWorthyList(argThat(isIn(setOfNames)));
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know this one

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with at least [answers](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html) and [argument captors](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html).

```
public class MyTest {
    class Idols {
        void addToNotWorthyList(String guitaristName) {
            //testing purposes
        }
    }

    private List<String> expectedValues = new ArrayList() {{
        add("Jeff Beck");
        add("Seasick Steve");
        add("Steve Howe");
    }};

    @Mock
    private Idols mock;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void checkWithAnswer() {
        doAnswer(new Answer() {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                String actualGuitarist = (String) invocation.getArguments()[0];
                assertTrue("Found unexpected guitarist [" + actualGuitarist + "]", expectedValues.contains(actualGuitarist));
                return null;
            }
        }).when(mock).addToNotWorthyList(anyString());

        mock.addToNotWorthyList("Jeff Beck");
        mock.addToNotWorthyList("Jeff");

        verify(mock, atLeast(0)).addToNotWorthyList(anyString());
    }

    @Test
    public void checkWithArgumentCaptor() {
        ArgumentCaptor<String> usedGuitarists = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);

        mock.addToNotWorthyList("Jeff Beck");
        mock.addToNotWorthyList("Jeff");

        verify(mock, atLeast(0)).addToNotWorthyList(usedGuitarists.capture());
        for (String actualGuitarist : usedGuitarists.getAllValues()) {
            assertTrue("Found unexpected guitarist [" + actualGuitarist + "]", expectedValues.contains(actualGuitarist));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW.. Here is what i came up with

```
public class SetMatcher<T> extends ArgumentMatcher<T> {

   private final Set<T> set;

   public MockitoSetMatcher(List<T> list) {
      set = new HashSet<T>(list);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean matches(Object argument) {
      return set.contains(argument);
   }

}
```

And then I use the

```
Mockito.argThat(new SetMatcher<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Jeff Beck", "Seasick Steve", "Steve Howe" } )));
```